# PrimeNg p-dropdown Does not Display Array Values

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng

I have component using PrimeNg p-dropdown.
html code:

```
<p-dropdown [style]="{'width':'150px'}" [options]="portNames" placeholder="Select a Port">
</p-dropdown>
```

ts portNames decleration:

```
portNames: string[] =["Port 01","Port 02", "Port 03"];
```

My Problem is that DropDown Does not Display Values "Port 01","Port 02", "Port 03".

Maybe I have any mistake?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding your dropdown values in label and values

```
portNames =[
{label:'Port 01', value:'Port 01'},
{label:'Port 02', value:'Port 02'},
{label:'Port 03', value:'Port 03'},
];
```

Comment: There's a mismatch between `string[]` and the array of objects you're assigning. There also should be quotes surrounding the values.

Comment: yes I referred to https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown and have made changes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

`portNames` should be an array of objects composed of a label and a value (not an array of strings) :

```
portNames = [
        {label:'Port 01', value:'p01'},
        {label:'Port 02', value:'p02'},
        {label:'Port 03', value:'p03'}
        ];
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Sc4jqnS8K8oAVCByWKMn?p=preview)

Comment: can i use other diff  object properties instead of label an value ? or is it necessary object array must have lablel and value .

Comment: Yes you can use *optionLabel* if you want to specify another property for the field name of the option.

Answer (score 2):

Its not necessary to use label and value in dropdown values. You can set optionLabel attribute in p-dropdown. This means value will be read from objects property the same as set in optionLabel attribute and will show up when calling item.label or selectedItem.label.

Comment: can you please give solution in code pls for this problem.

Comment: @FengZhang:
`[{ id: 1, description: 'blah }, { id: 2, description: 'poop'}]`

Using an object like that as your `:options` on your `<Dropdown>`, you can spec `optionLabel="description"`, and it will display your description property value.

Answer (score 1):

Getting PrimeNG p-dropdown to work with array of strings is possible, though it is not well documented. I use it sometimes when selecting timezones.  There might be cleaner options, but I use ng-template to populate the dropdown and onChange to store the selected string value:

**HTML**

```
<p-dropdown [style]="{'width':'150px'}" [options]="portNames" placeholder="Select a Port" (onChange)="storeValue($event)">
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="selectedItem"> 
    {{item}} 
  </ng-template> 
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item"> 
    {{item}}
  </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

**Component.ts**

```
portNames: string[] =["Port 01","Port 02", "Port 03"];    

selectedPort="";

storeValue(event) {
    console.log(event); //event.value will likely be undefined, check event.originalEvent
    this.selectedPort = event.originalEvent.srcElement.innerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a mix response for this that it works for me.

**HTML**

```
<p-dropdown [options]="portNames" placeholder="Select a Port" (onChange)="storeValue($event)">
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="selectedItem"> 
    {{item.item}} 
  </ng-template> 
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item"> 
    {{item.item}}
  </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

**Component**

```
portNames = [
        {label:'Port 01', value:'p01'},
        {label:'Port 02', value:'p02'},
        {label:'Port 03', value:'p03'}
        ];
    selectedPort="";
    
    storeValue(event) {
        console.log("Selected item value:", event.event.value);
        this.selectedPort = event.event.value;
    }
```